# AS3: how to organize classes for my api implementation?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I am developing an Air application that interacts with my server. There are plenty of various methods related to different subjects.

To structure that, I introduce a master 'API' object and several extenders of it, each implementing methods for particular Subject. Each of them uses the master API `_call` method that actually makes a call to server.

How do I set the master API, so that I could reference its children like so:

```java
var Api:myMasterApi = Application.getApi();

// Now do the API calls:
Api.Subject1.Method1();
Api.Subject2.Method3();
```

I tryed setting MasterApi public static properties to the instantiated subclasses, perhaps in a wrong way:

```java
class myMasterApi {
    public static Subject1:mySubject1 = new mySubject1();
    public static Subject2:mySubject2 = new mySubject2();

    protected function _call( args... ) { /* does the call */ }
}
```

And the extenders are like so:

```java
class mySubject1 extends myMasterApi {
    public function Method1( args... ) {
        prepare things;
        this._call( args ); // do the call
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach to a structured implementation of API, or I'm on the wrong track?

The problem I'm stuck with is that when `Api.Subject1` is not `static` it creates stack overflow by circular self reference: as its base class has `Subject1` as a property.

When Api.Subject1 is `static`, it gives error 1119: "Access of possibly undefined property post through a reference with static type ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up two different fundamental OOP concepts: composition and inheritence. It probably doesn't make any sense for your specific `Subject` classes to be extending `MasterApi` (inheritence) AND have the `MasterApi` contain an instance of each of its descendents. It *is* circular.

What you may want to do instead is have a base `Subject` class that each of the specific `Subjects` extends, so that they can all use some common methods, and then have your `MasterApi` be an unrelated class that contains a singleton instance of each of your specific `Subjects`.

'Singleton' is just a term meaning "it's an instance (not a static class), but there is only and exactly one of them". This is exactly what you get by declaring your `static` properties and setting them to new instances of the specific `Subject` classes.

A barebones example (excluding `imports` statements, etc). I have no idea what your "subjects" are so I just present some made up properties:

```
class SubjectBase {
    private var _name:String;
    private var _description:String;

    public function SubjectBase() {  }

    protected function loadSubject(subjectID:String):void {
        var qResult:Object = SomeClass.SomeMethodThatQueriesYourServer(subjectID);
        _name = qResult["SUBJECT_NAME"];
        _description = qResult["SUBJECT_DESC"];
    }

    public function get name():String {
        return _name;
    }

    public function get description():String {
        return _description;
    }
}

class Subject1 extends SubjectBase {
    public function Subject1() {
        super();
        loadSubject("SUBJECT1");
    }
}

class Subject2 extends SubjectBase {
    public function Subject2() {
        super();
        loadSubject("SUBJECT2");
    }
}

class MasterApi {
    private static _subject1:Subject1 = new Subject1();
    private static _subject2:Subject2 = new Subject2();
    public function MasterApi() { }
    public static function get subject1():Subject1 { return _subject1; }
    public static function get subject2():Subject2 { return _subject2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `Subject1` and `Subject2` to be static?  If so, `myMasterApi.Subject1` is how you get to those static items.

Instead, you probably want to remove the static from the definitions, and everything should work for you.

Comment: When Subject1 is not static, initialization of myMasterApi follows to stack overflow by a circular reference: child subClass inherits the property Subject1 and creates another copy of itself - and further on.